# Design alignment prob in HTML

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this picture below that I want to convert into web from a windows. I manage to do the design but I have a problem in the grid `(I am using data tables in bootstrap)` I can't do the design in what in the picture like.

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" />
                Radio Button
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" />
            Radio Button
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            < div>
                < input type="button" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table >
<table >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                               < i class="fa fa-list fa-fw" >< / i >Table
                                < /div >
                            < /div>
                        < /div>
                        < !-- /.panel-heading -->
                        < div class="panel-body">
                            < div class="dataTable_wrapper">
           < table class="table table-striped table-bordered  table-hover table-responsive nowrap"
                   role="grid" style="width: 100%;" id="dataTables-xxxx">
                   </table>
            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            < /div>
        </td>
        <td>
         <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    < i class="fa fa-list fa-fw"></i>Table
                                < /div>
                            < /div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive nowrap"
                                    role="grid" style="width: 100%;" id="dataTables-xxasdxx">
                                </table>
                            < /div>
                        < /div>
                    < /div>
                < /div>
            < /div>
        </ td>
    < /tr>
< /table>
```

My 2 Images bellow:
[image: 1st Images]

[image: 2nd Images]

Comment: you want your design to be like picture 1 or picture 2 ???

Comment: I am following the design from picture. My current output is the picture 2.

Comment: Code like `</table>< /div>< /div>< /div>< /div>< /div></ td>< /tr>< /table>` is rarely a good sign.Tables should only be used for tabular data and not layout. Usings tables for layout goes against pretty much everything Bootstrap stands for.

Comment: @JonP can you share an example?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below design hope it helps.You can customize the column property as your desire I just added the basic skeleton.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">


<div class=" col-sm-12 form-group">
 <div class=" col-sm-2">
  <input type="radio" />
                Radio Button
  </div >
   <div class=" col-sm-2">
    <input type="radio" />
                Radio Button
     </div >
    </div >
 
<div class=" col-sm-12 form-group ">
 <div class=" col-sm-2">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
 </div>
<div class=" col-sm-2">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
 </div>
  </div>
 

  <div class="table-responsive col-md-6">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="col-md-1">#</th>
                  <th class="col-md-2">Header</th>
                  <th class="col-md-3">Header</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
  <div class="table-responsive col-md-6">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="col-md-1">#</th>
                  <th class="col-md-2">Header</th>
                  <th class="col-md-3">Header</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  </body>
```

**Or See the below fiddle for a better look**

[table design demo fiddle (updated)](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/15344/)

Comment: @Redoy What I want is how can I make my design like the picture 1?. Like the Table in picture 1 and look my output they have the same size. T_T

Comment: oh you want two tables with different size according to the picture ?others are okay??

Comment: see the updated fiddle and  let me know if it works for you or not .

Comment: @Redoy lastly. How can I make the 1st Data table make it small than the 2nd Data Table like in the picture 1 in my post.

Comment: did you check the fiddle which I updated ?? well in bootstrap it depends on your grid whether small or big  you can also use custom css but using grid is easy at the first place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125970/discussion-between-ki-v2-and-asifuzzaman-redoy).

Answer (score 1):

You can also, do something like this instead of using tables for layout and mimic as close as to your conversion UI.

table tags are meant primarily for data formatting. Bootstrap has the concept of grid layout which is meant for laying out your UI without using tables.

When you open the snippet in full screen, you would see the exact replica. However, when the screen is too small to fit in your entire content, it just wraps into the next row, giving you the flexibility to build responsive layout, which is not possible with table tags.

```css
.custom-margin {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="custom-container">
  <div class="radio">
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="" id="optionsRadiosOne" value="optionOne">Radio Button One
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="" id="optionsRadiosTwo" value="optionTwo">Radio Button Two
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-margin">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputName2">Enter Email :</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send invitation</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
          <td>Header One
          </td>
          <td>Header Two
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Row Content
          </td>

          <td>Row Content
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Row Content
          </td>

          <td>Row Content
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
          <td>Header One
          </td>
          <td>Header Two
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Row Content
          </td>

          <td>Row Content
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Row Content
          </td>

          <td>Row Content
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```